# The set of polynomial functions is finitely generated

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $P(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all polynomial functions in $\mathbb{R}$.
How do i show that this vector space is finitely generated. I know that i need to show that $P(\mathbb{R})=spanV$ where V is a set of some vectors in $P(\mathbb{R})$.

I am trying to show that this is true by justifying that they are subsets of each other. I'm having truble picking the vector, and understand how one vector can fit it $spanV$.

Comment: The big problem you're facing is that $P(\mathbb{R})$ is infinite-dimensional. Is there perhaps a bound on the degree?

Comment: It would also be good to point out here that "sets" aren't finitely generated, vector spaces, rings, groups algebras etc are finitely generated. If you don't specify which, then you are at the mercy of readers' imagnations. Presumably here you had "vector space" in mind, but didn't say so, and now you can see why "set" wasn't very informative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\mathbb R)$ is not finitely generated as a vector space, since it is infinite-dimensional. It is finitely-generated as an algebra over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm trying to do this as a problem in the book using the theorem that if a functon is finitely generated, it satisfies the theorem aove. I haven't found the infinite dimensional definition yet. Can I do this lroblem using a conteadiction to the theorem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what it means for a function to be "finitely generated", nor I know what the "theorem above" is.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: As a *vector space*, $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\dots\}$ can be used as a basis for the real polynomials. All bases of the space have the same size... what's the size of this basis?

As an *$\Bbb R$-algebra*, you can produce any polynomial just starting with the two-element set $\{1,x\}$.